# There is a way to throw arguments {} on the react render side of the onChange method

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
onChange={this.handleChange({no=data.no})}

handleChange = ({no=0}) =>{

}
```

Is there a way to get it in react jsx?

Comment: you need to rephrase you question, not clear. or probably you need this: `onChange={() => this.handleChange({no: data.no})}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this syntax:

```
onChange={() => this.handleChange({no: data.no})}
```